# jest does not collect coverage for vue file in case it just have defineProps and defineEmit in scripts

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, code-coverage, vue-sfc

i am not sure why Jest coverage behavior changes in below scenario

it does not collect a coverage if i have code like below.

```
<template>
  <Teleport to="body">
    <div v-if="show" class="modal">
      <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="message xxl">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
        <button class="button button--info" @click="$emit('reset')">
          continue
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Teleport>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
  show: Boolean,
});
defineEmits(["reset"]);
</script>
```

[coverage not collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0Ol1.png)

but if i just add a dummy console statement it works

```
<template>
  <Teleport to="body">
    <div v-if="show" class="modal">
      <div class="modal_content">
        <div class="message xxl">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
        <button class="button button--info" @click="$emit('reset')">
          continue
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Teleport>
</template>

<script setup>
defineProps({
  show: Boolean,
});
console.log("--silent");
defineEmits(["reset"]);
</script>
```

[coverage get collected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUwGg.png)

any thoughts on why it is happening like this ?

Comment: I test it and effectively I have the same problem